# Properly structuring a Java Spring framework project for multiple web applications

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I am working on a project using the Java Spring framework, but I am (even after googling or looking through tutorials) unable to understand how it should be used.

**Situation:**
The project is(or, will be) made up of 3 separate web applications(for three different uses/target audiences) that uses the same database and to some extent functions and/or classes.
Database/cryptography-related classes and such are in a common folder under the project root, which seems appropriate.
Then there is a folder for gradle, used for starting the program("./gradlew app-one:bootRun"), which I suppose makes sense.
Then, there is a folder for one of the web applications("app-one") with related source code(Controllers, Services, etc.) and whatnot.

**Problem:**
I am tasked with adding the second application. Is it suppose to be a separate folder in the root directory?(Logically/By framework standards)
If it is not, how do I know what belongs to which application?
Do I need to use separate gradle commands to start each of the three applications? Is that even possible, and is it recommended/efficient/the best way to structure everything?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use maven,you can create a multi-module maven project with parent pom having all dependency management.A core project(jar) having all core functionality and three web projects(war) for your web modules which depend on this core project.You can start build and run these projects with a bat script from one place only.

Comment: Thanks! Let me just ask something for clarification: Do you mean "it's not possible with gradle", or do you mean "at the very least, it's possible with maven"?

Comment: I don't know much about gradle.This might be possible with gradle also.But it's definitely possible with maven.

Comment: OP specifically mentioned Gradle and there was not a single word about Maven.